# iOS Table View Cell not resizing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I inherited a custom `UITableViewCell` in a project that I'm working on and now have to resize an `image view` and a few `labels` within the cell.  However, in order to make the larger `subviews` fit I would like to resize the `UITableViewCell`.  So in the `storyboard` I changed the Row Height field, however no matter how large I make this number the `cell`'s size still doesn't change and the rest of my `views` feel crammed in there.

Comment: did u selected the checkbox "Custome Cell" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that your view controller is delegate for your table view, then implement the following two delegate methods:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For best performance, if height for different rows differs, cache the heights in some array.

The estimate method is not required, but helps the tableview position quicker.

Comment: is right, it's likely they've already implemented tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath which is overriding any changes you are making on the Storyboard.

Comment: This worked, although I'm still not sure, what's the difference between setting the height programmatically like this vs using the custom row height in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Go in the `StoryBoard` and click on your `custome cell` and then in the `size inspector`, check **custom** and set row height = whatever you want.